# Taking over a Joomla created site

Tags: joomla

So i have a client, who has a disc of an entire site.  Root server files, all the way to /httphome/ files...

However, it looks like it was created using Joomla.  Now, i know my HTMl and CSS but have never used a CMS like Joomla.

To get this site up and running, am i going to have to install Joomla on my clients server, and then upload the files?

i am going to assume its not that easy.... anyone got any insight into this process and what im looking at?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Joomla content resides in a MySql database. 
You need the following:

- Database export
- Create a DB on you MySQL server
- Upload the files
- Edit configuration.php to work with you db and also set your path there

Also, some components might need some more setup, as some of them have their own cfg files.

Comment: The database is most important part as that is where all the information is stored.

Answer (score 1):

To get this site up and running (if the file is really the entire site) should be as simple as setting up a web server and pointing it to the directory with the index in it. Joomla should already be in that file. Let me know if i can elaborate on the process.

Comment: You got it just before I did.  You'll just need to set up the database, enable PHP in the webserver and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to Joomla, you might want to try loading the disc contents up on your localhost first.  Personally, when I'm trying something new, I hate for my first attempts to be somewhat public - I always feel a little safer if I do the first install someplace local where I'm the only person who can see it.

Best of luck with your project!  If you run into any problems, or if you want to confirm that the site is definitely Joomla, let us know and we will get you sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the related database? The files that make up Joomla are useless without the database. You could install Joomla and upload your files over the top, but any database changes made by any installed extensions wouldn't be made to that install. You'd also be missing all of the actual site content without the database.

If you do have the database, then all you need to do is import the database in you your mySQL, then upload the files you have on the disc and edit configuration.php file with the new database user and password.